# missing org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils

Tags: maven, apache-commons

I import commons-lang3 as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But I can not found sub package collections in package org.apache.commons.lang3

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will not find it in this jar. Maybe  you are looking for the  commons-collections artifact:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In both of them, you will find the class CollectionUtils.
But, in your case, I think the version 3.2.2 will fit better.

Comment: You mean there is no class CollectionUtils in commons-lang3 artifact, so I should import commons-collections artifact, right?

Comment: Yes, you should import commons-collections and there is no CollectionUtils in commons-lang3.

Comment: example of use: import org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils;